# Why this Integer comparison in Groovy is returning false?

Tags: groovy, integer

I've found a bug in my project because of the following behavior:

```
int a = 1
Integer b = 2
assert a.class == b.class // ok, they are the same class
assert Integer.class != int.class // what?! they are different!
```

Somebody knows why and how to handle this?

I'm using Groovy 2.3.7
Regards

Comment: Integer is a class, while int is a primitive data type.

Comment: There's a good explanation [here](http://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html).

Comment: if you evaluate `println(a.class)` what do you think it will show you?

Comment: Good idea! It returns class `java.lang.Integer`. So, now I understood the problem: the "a" is being converted to Integer (not primitive type). That's why `a.class == b.class`. Makes sense. Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @alfasin link and @Nathan comments, I've discovered that the a is being autocoverted (autoboxing) to Integer.

That's why `a.class == b.class` but `Integer.class != int.class`

In my specific problem I'm using reflection to get the class of a field using `clazz.getDeclaredFields()`. The value in class is int, but the value that I have to compare is Integer.

To solve this I'm using the helper class below, which converts int to Integer for me:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.ClassUtils
ClassUtils.primitiveToWrapper(int.class) == Integer.class
```

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Or use `@CompileStatic` or `@TypeChecked`